# Isolate substring after the first n characters and before the last n characters

Tags: php, return, substr, text-extraction, strpos

Using the `substr()` how do I remove the first and last 3 characters in a string and return the middle remaining characters?
eg:

```
$a = 'abc34828xyz';
$a = 'abc347283828xyz';
$a = 'abc347w83828xyz';
// return first 3
return $first = substr($a, 0, 3);
// return last 3
return $last = substr($a, -3);
// return the string in middle
// $mid = ? now how do we always get the ones in the middle
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(Just start with an offset of 3 and then take the length where you subtract 2*3 (6))

```
echo $middle = substr($a, 3, strlen($a)-6);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace):

```
$a = 'abc347w83828xyz';
$mid = preg_replace('/...(.*).../', '$1', $a);
echo $mid, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
347w83828
```

And if you want you can actually get them all at once by using a [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) call:

```
$a = 'abc347w83828xyz';
preg_match('/(...)(.*)(...)/', $a, $matches);

echo "First: ", $matches[1], PHP_EOL;
echo "Mid:   ", $matches[2], PHP_EOL;
echo "Last:  ", $matches[3], PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
First: abc
Mid:   347w83828
Last:  xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants a generic way to just return middle character of a string:

```
function getMiddle($text): string
{
    $length = round((strlen($text)) / 2);
    if (strlen($text) % 2 === 0)
    {
        //even, returns 2 characters
        return $text[(int) $length - 1] . $text[(int) $length];
    }
    //odd, returns 1 character
    return $text[(int) $length - 1];
}
```

or

```
function getMiddle($text): string
{
    $start = floor((strlen($text) - 1) / 2);
    $len = strlen($text) % 2 ? 1 : 2;
    return substr($text, $start, $len);
}

echo getMiddle("middle") . PHP_EOL;
echo getMiddle("testing") . PHP_EOL;
echo getMiddle("A") . PHP_EOL;
```

output:

```
dd
t
A
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `substr()` with a starting offset of 3 and a negative limit parameter to indicate how many offsets to subtract from the end of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PInU8))

```
$string = 'abc347w83828xyz';
echo substr($string, 3, -3);  '347w83828'
```

For clarity, if your input string is `abcde`, then the returned value will be an empty string.